# Removing blank rows in the two data frames and combine them

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset which contains two groups. First 3 columns are 1st group and next 3 columns are 2nd group. They contains missing values at random manner.
I have to delete the rows containing complete missing values in any one group. And both group contains at least one value in the row.
At last I have to combine both the groups.
I have tried many R codes. Please suggest some useful R function for this issue.

example data structure

[image]

Comment: It always helps to add the example as a text in the question and show the "Many R codes" that you used. Makes it easier to find/give an answer the suits your specific problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think your explanations are not very clear, particularly what does "And both group contains at least one value in the row." means and what do you mean by "combine" ? please edit your post by editing an example of your expected output or provide clearer explanations

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://www.statology.org/r-remove-rows-with-na-in-one-column/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is properly named, this can be done using `starts_with` and `if_any` (otherwise you might rename your columns first as you see fit)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~x1, ~x2, ~x3, ~y1, ~y2, ~y3,
  26.4, 26.5, 26.6, 26.7, 26.4, 26.5,
  NA, NA, NA, 23.7, NA, NA,
  27.2, 28.0, 27.9, 27.6, 27.8, 27.7,
  NA, 24.2, 24.9, 23.9, 24.9, 24.0,
  24.3, NA, 24.3, 24.0, 24.1, 24.5,
  26.9, 26.7, 27.0, 26.9, 26.8, 26.8,
  24.4, 24.4, 24.5, 24.8, 24.3, 24.3,
  NA, NA, NA, 23.9, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, 23.9, NA, NA,
  24.9, NA, NA, 24.9, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, 24.5, NA, NA,
  28.3, 28.2, 28.3, 28.2, 28.4, 28.3,
  28.3, 28.4, 28.1, 28.3, 28.3, 28.2
)


df %>% filter(!if_all(starts_with("x"), is.na) & !if_all(starts_with("y"), is.na))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>      x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  26.4  26.5  26.6  26.7  26.4  26.5
#> 2  27.2  28    27.9  27.6  27.8  27.7
#> 3  NA    24.2  24.9  23.9  24.9  24  
#> 4  24.3  NA    24.3  24    24.1  24.5
#> 5  26.9  26.7  27    26.9  26.8  26.8
#> 6  24.4  24.4  24.5  24.8  24.3  24.3
#> 7  24.9  NA    NA    24.9  NA    NA  
#> 8  28.3  28.2  28.3  28.2  28.4  28.3
#> 9  28.3  28.4  28.1  28.3  28.3  28.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonathan.  This is working as my wish...

Comment: @KABILAN, please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem; that would be very helpful for others having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but here is a demonstration using `dplyr::if_all()` , `dplyr::if_any()`

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Example data
# have to delete the rows containing complete missing values in any one group. 
# And both group contains at least one value in the row. (Not sure what that means)
# At last I have to combine both the groups. 
d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~gr1_col1, ~gr1_col2, ~gr1_col3, ~gr2_col1, ~gr2_col2, ~gr2_col3,
  1, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1,
  NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1,
  1, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA,
)
d
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   gr1_col1 gr1_col2 gr1_col3 gr2_col1 gr2_col2 gr2_col3
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1        1        2       NA        1        1        1
#> 2       NA       NA       NA       NA        1        1
#> 3       NA        1        1       NA       NA        1
#> 4        1       NA        2       NA       NA       NA
d %>% 
  dplyr::filter(
    # First group
    !dplyr::if_all(.cols = c(1, 2, 3), .fns = is.na), # removing rows if all columns 1, 2 and 3 are NA
    # second group
    !if_all(.cols = c(4, 5, 6), .fns = is.na) # removing rows if all columns 1, 2 and 3 are NA
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   gr1_col1 gr1_col2 gr1_col3 gr2_col1 gr2_col2 gr2_col3
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1        1        2       NA        1        1        1
#> 2       NA        1        1       NA       NA        1
# Not sure what you mean with how you want to combine groups
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone suggestions. Thanks to @olivroy.  Though you are not understand my question clearly (it is my fault only:-)…, you were given the exact code which I need for my work.